# Reloading modernizr after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, reload

I have part of a page being dynamically refreshed via the jQuery load() method, but its not looking so hot in IE. Short of rewriting the mark-up to suite ie, I would like to reload modernizr after the ajax and have it re-work its magic to the newly inserted content. Is this possible? hopefully via the load() callback somehow?

*updated with my code*
I have my scripts.js loaded at the bottom of the page with the following:
(using the jquery address plugin here to determine when to load the new content)

```
function ajaxLoad(){
  $.address.change(function(event) {    
    $("#swap-content").fadeOut('fast').load(event.value+' #swap-content', pageFunctions);
  };
};

function pageFunctions() {
  $("#swap-content").fadeIn('fast');
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  ajaxLoad();
});
```

and then I have the modernizr loaded in the head as such
`<script src="/js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>`
So my goal is to have modernizr re-bedazzle the contents of '#swap-content' when it gets reloaded via load().

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Show us some sample code so we have a better idea what the problem is and how we can help you.

Comment: what sort of bedazzling are you expecting that you're not getting? i'm unclear.

Comment: I wanted to use some html5 tags in my content, 'article' and 'section' etc. and I'm using modernizr to bedazzle them for ie. But since modernizr doesn't reload after the ajax call, the newly inserted html5 tags remain unstyled in ie after the load() event.

Comment: related: http://forum.lemonstandapp.com/topic/1877-html5modernizr-and-ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with html5shiv.
This should do the trick: http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/

Comment: my work wouldn't let me update modernizer how ironic this was helpful